# How can Node.js read 30 TB data from HDFS fast?

Tags: node.js, hadoop, bigdata

At first I just use pipe and normal reading and writing, but the speed is very slow. The server has 700 GB memory. Is there some methods that can make the reading and writing faster? 
I have other two servers but less memory that I can use.

Comment: What's the source how are you writing..?

Comment: Hi, the source is from Hadoop. I write to the memory. I try my best to compress the data so it won't take 30TB to save the data.

Comment: If source is hadoop then you have much more ways to make it fast. Could you update the details with question what's this and what have you tried so far, code.